# Equivalent of `objcopy -O binary <FILE> <FILE>.bin` for Mach-O object files on macOS?

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, mach

Equivalent of `objcopy -O binary <FILE> <FILE>.bin` for Mach-O object files in macOS?

I want to dump the executable code in the `__TEXT` segment to a flat binary file on macOS.

This can be accomplished on Linux as follows:

`objcopy -O binary <FILE> <FILE>.bin`, where `<FILE>` would be an ELF file.

However, since `objcopy` isn't available (or very poorly supported) on macOS (e.g. `llvm-objcopy` cannot handle Mach-O objects), how can I achieve the same result?

Comment: You could install the GNU binutils (e.g. with brew) and use that.

Comment: `brew` just mentions that GNU binutils is "poorly" supported on macOS, so I'm afraid of using it, if it's full of bugs. Do you have good experience with it?

Comment: I don't have experience with it on macOS.  Have you tried using it?  `objcopy` performs a pretty simple functionality, so unless binutils are really broken, it should work.

Comment: Given that `llvm-objcopy` doesn't support what you want to do at all, something that's supposedly "poorly" supports what you want to do would be a better alternative.

Comment: I needed to strip debug symbols from object and create a separate debug symbols file and I could achieve that with `dsymutil` and `strip` commands. I don't know if they can be used also for your operation.